# Java - Wait() not quite working in the order

Tags: java, javafx, wait

I have an array of int values displayed on my scene and when I use a search bar and find a value such as "23", it will turn the text of the "23" red on the list of ints. I want it to wait, then turn back black but my wait() doesn't seem to work quite right.

```
search.setOnKeyPressed(new EventHandler<KeyEvent>()
    {
        public void handle(KeyEvent ke)
        {
            if (ke.getCode().equals(KeyCode.ENTER))
            {
                int value = Integer.parseInt(search.getText());
                System.out.println("Value: " + value);
                if (list.contains(value)){
                    txtArray[value].setFill(Color.RED);
                    try{
                        Thread.sleep(1000);
                        txtArray[value].setFill(Color.BLACK);
                    }
                    catch (Exception e){
                        System.out.println("caught");
                    }
                }
                else{
                    error.setText(value + " was not found");
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

What it does instead is just goes straight to black, skipping the Red altogether. If I comment out

```
//Thread.sleep(1000); 
//txtArray[value].setFill(Color.BLACK);
```

it works flawlessly turning the text Red.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. I'm not quite sure that your question is. Please be a little bit more precise.

Comment: You are blocking the FX Application thread, preventing it from rendering until the handler is complete. You should use a `PauseTransition` for this.